# Simplify list filtering on the fly

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have searched for days now, but I didn't found any adapted answer to my question. I try to simplify this kind of filtering :

```
omega = list()

for elt in db_cursor:
    if elt not in omega:
        omega.append(elt)
```

I try to fusion the last two lines but I didn't succeed to do that. I want to fulfill a list with elements from a SQLite cursor (note the source can come from other kind of generator or something else...).

I tried different list comprehension syntax but nothing work so far.

So if somebody could help, he will welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand the question... So what you are trying to do is fill the `omega` list with elements from `db_cursor`, but you want to avoid duplicates (hence `if elt not in omega`, right?)

This won't work in a list comprehension, as the list itself is changing.

But, you mention that `db_cursor` is a result from a SQL database. If you want to avoid duplicates, you should start a step earlier with the `SELECT DISTINCT` query. This way you can just do:

```
omega = [elt for elt in db_cursor]
```

because the duplicates have been eliminated with the `DISTINCT` selector.

Another way to filter out duplicates would be to convert it to a set and then back

```
omega = list(set(omega))
```

as sets can't contain duplicates.

Comment: Hi Papooch, you understood well the question. I've forgot to mention that the data are splitted in four tables with the same format in the DB.

Comment: Your first solution will not work. The second is ok but, my wish is to simplify the test.

Comment: To be honest, it seems like a bad design on the SQL side. You should never have to filter the results in the front end, as the database engine is optimised for exactly these tasks.
If the data is split in 4 tables (I assume 4 different sources), how come there could be duplicates? I don't see inside your database, but I would suggest merging all the tables together and adding a new field specifying the source.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the hand on the DB design because it's from a iVi system, a Call Data Records exactly.